# Select Top 1 vs Unique Id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I would like to know if there is any detriment in performance on using a "select top 1" on a table that has a unique identifier column on which I do all my searches on.

This is more in the line of "should I leave the top 1" for readability on the developer side or does the top 1 affect performance speed? Is it even useful since my query should return only one record each time?

Comment: Are you saying that for the `WHERE` you are using, that only 1 row will be returned? If so, the `TOP 1` does seem some what superfluous.

Comment: Is that query ordered by some column(s)? If yes, keep the `TOP 1` ;-)

Comment: I'd be suspicious of a `TOP 1` with no obvious purpose. Like using `DISTINCT` for no obvious reason, it's more likely to make *me* think that the developer was getting multiple results when they expected one and decided not to get to the bottom of why it was happening.

Comment: @Larnu yes. My where is something like "where ID = @parameterFromOutside" and ID is a unique identifier column.

Comment: I agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever here. Having a `TOP 1` implies that multiple rows *could* be returned. So something like `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE UniqueID = @uniqueidentifier;` would suggest to me that `UniqueID` isn't very unique. If the query is only going to return 1 row, because of the nature of querying a column with a unique constraint, then you should omit the `TOP 1`.

Comment: Hello, @deHaar , the query is not sorted. Thou I have thought of something. Doesn't the top 1 prevent the query from going trought the rest of the records once it finds at least one match? Like a "break" in a "while"?

Comment: @RazvanIonescu If the column is a unique index then the engine knows it doesn't need to keep looking, as has already been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main question is wether you have an index ([accepter answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435356/performance-effect-of-using-top-1-in-a-select-query)) on your unique column or not.

If you have an index (either you added it or we are talking about the primary key of the table) then the search for the unique value will happen before even reading the table, and the TOP 1 will not make any difference, as the query planner will see that there is only one value anyway. So in this case, TOP 1 does not affect performance.

If you do not have an index, it is not really determinable what exeqution plan will be generated. We can see cases when the TOP 1 actually confuses te query planner ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435356/performance-effect-of-using-top-1-in-a-select-query) in the comments or [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/why-does-adding-a-top-1-dramatically-worsen-performance)) and causes worse performance by using wrong types of join, or if an ORDER BY is present, mistakenly materializing the whole table. So in this case, TOP 1 can even cause performance downgrade.

Also, there is the readability issue that @Damien_The_Unbeliever and @Larnu mentioned: it's easier to understand the intention of the writer if the code does not contain the unnecessary TOP 1.

So what I would do: make sure the unique column is properly indexed and leave the TOP 1.

Comment: Hello, @Annosz Thank you for your answer. Another thing that I forgot to mention is if the top 1 acts like a break in a while statement. If, as soon as it finds a match the query does not go trough the rest of the records that have not been checked yet. Also, the unique column I am using is the primary key of the table. The query checks only one table (so no joins). I'm basically asking if the top 1 even matters or not since I know the query will not have duplicates on the primary key, but maybe I can speed up searching?

Comment: @RazvanIonescu If the column is a unique index, there is no notional 'while' statement; any barely decent database engine would know not to keep searching once it found the single match that can exist. Just don't worry about it, and don't include pointless/red-herring `top 1`s anywhere.

Comment: In this case the TOP 1 should not matter: as I wrote in the second paragraph, the query execution will first check the indexes (the primary key has a clustered index by default in sql server), and will filter the 1 row there. It won't even access the table for finding multiple rows, so there is no "while" that the TOP 1 would break.